# Why is the indefinite integral $e^\frac{x}{2}x^\frac{g}{2}dx$ the upper Gamma function in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have an indefinite integral $e^\frac{x}{2}x^\frac{g}{2}dx$,

I try to solve in *Mathematica*.

```
Solve[Int[e^{x/2}x^{g/2-1}dx ,x]]
(* Gamma[g/2,x/2] *)
```

How does Mathematica decide the range of integral? Why do they use the upper Gamma function here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please include the actual code you used, properly formatted for Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
Solve[Int[e^{x/2} x^{g/2 - 1} dx, x]]
```

is completely invalid for finding the indefinite integral of

```
E^(x/2) x^(g/2 - 1)
```

with respect to `x`. The correct formulation is

```
Integrate[E^(x/2) x^(g/2 - 1), x]
```

which produces

> ```
> ((-2^(g/2))*x^(g/2)*Gamma[g/2, -(x/2)])/(-x)^(g/2)
> ```

That this is a correct result is confirmed by taking the derivative of the result

```
D[((-2^(g/2))*x^(g/2)*Gamma[g/2, -(x/2)])/(-x)^(g/2),x]//Simplify
```

which gives back the original integrand.

> ```
> E^(x/2)*x^(-1 + g/2)
> ```

#### Update

As Bob Hanlon points out in his comment, another correct result with a different form can be had from

```
Integrate[E^(x/2) x^(g/2 - 1), x] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> (-x^(g/2))*ExpIntegralE[1 - g/2, -(x/2)]
> ```

and can be verified with

```
D[-x^(g/2) ExpIntegralE[1 - g/2, -(x/2)], x] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: You can use `FullSimplify` on the result to express the integral in an equivalent form: `(-x^(g/2))*ExpIntegralE[1 - g/2, -(x/2)]`

Comment: ...and of course, the exponential integral and incomplete gamma function are essentially equivalent.